# We need to improve our [resource-utilization]

Tags: discussion, status-declined, burninate-request

The [resource-utilization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/resource-utilization) tag has ten questions, two watchers, and its highest-voted answer has four votes (from a grand total of 6 answers).

The questions are tagged with a copious amount of well-known/used languages/environments:

- [android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android)
- [r](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/r)
- [scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/scala)
- [docker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/docker)
- [php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php)
- [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java)
- [linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/linux)
- [bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bash)

This tag has no tag wiki, and no creation date.

Due to the lack of interest in this tag, I suggest it be burnèd.

Comment: If a tag has a low number of questions and fewer number of watchers then it should not necessarily mean that it is useless.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The topic by itself seems on-topic, if it is about CPU / Memory utilization. And most of the questions with that tag are. The only odd one out seems to be [extract probablity density values from kernel estimator in adehabitatHR](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53072828/578411).

Having no tag wiki, low number of questions or a large distribution over other tags are no reasons to remove it. There are no compelling arguments a burn is warranted.

I'm not convinced this tag needs to be burninated. It can stay.

Comment: This is a poor argument, specially since it ignores cases where this tag didn't allow for more relevant tags to be applied [like this one](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/55007578/revisions). Remember, every question requires a tag. If a irrelevant tag gets applied, then it's very unlikely that the question will be solved.

Comment: @Braiam if more then 5 tags can be applied to a question we might as well close it as too broad. If that limit is a problem, let's address that or tell followers in any of those tags to do a better job. Burninating a tag because it occupied all available tag slots on a question is a poor argument as well.

Comment: No, it's not. Questions left unanswered because poor tagging is the perfect argument. There's nothing more pernicious that preventing valid questions to be answered (really, I can't think of anything worse for SE model of Q&A). Tag selection is critical in these cases. Also, remember that the system suggest the tags you should be using. Askers aren't very aware of the implication of using tags (C/C++/C# anyone?), which makes them more confident on the system. If this tag didn't exist, the asker would be more likely select the correct tag from a limited pool of possible tags.

Comment: @Braiam it is ten questions, go ahead with the burn then.